# Updating mysql data using SIM900 and Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, gsm

Thanks in advance for your kind support.
I am not an expert but have little understanding of concepts and trying to integrate various things to get some useful projects for my purpose. I want to update the database (MySQL) on shared hosting using the SIM900A module and Arduino nano board. With help of examples shared on this platform and my understanding, I achieved a significant part of the same.  The following is the approach I have adopted and the current status:

I have put a PHP code on the server (shared hosting) to update the database once it received the GET request
I have also uploaded the code in the Arduino with proper connections for sending requests to the server.

Problems I am facing:
I am not able to update the data on my specific database, through the Arduino sent request. the same code is working with Thingspeak, My code is also working otherwise, as I have tested through web form request and URL request. I am not sure where is the problem.  I am also not getting any errors. The response to the AT request is "OK" only
Though I can update the Thingspeak channel, only till the command lesser than 61 characters, which are sent after the AT+CIPSEND command. There is no error, even if the request size increases, but data updated only till 61 characters (including \x1A character)
"I am wondering, is this the limit, that cannot be increased or there is some possibility to increase it."
I understand that the problem appears to be in approach and not in code, as the code is working in itself. However, please let me know, which code I need to share, as it is a multifile code on the web-editor

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue. It happened due to an SSL issue. You can find all info about it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950561/sim800l-gsm-module-working-with-http-and-shows-error-with-https-why